# The account is not authorized to log in from this station

Tags: windows, samba, smb, windows-10-preview, cifs

I'm using `Samba Version-4.1.6-Ubuntu`. I can connect to it fine from `Mac OS 10.x` and `Win 8` & `8.1`. As soon as installed the `Win 10 technical preview` i get the message `The account is not authorized to log in from this station.`

I have done/tried the following:

```
- Rebooted the client
- Rebooted the server
- Upgraded all the packages on the server
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanworkstation\parameters\enablesecuritysignature 1
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanworkstation\parameters\requiresecuritysignature 0
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters\enablesecuritysignature 1
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters\requiresecuritysignature 0
```

**smb.conf**

```
[global]
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    log level = 1
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully*$
    obey pam restrictions = yes
    socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_THROUGHPUT
    map to guest = bad user
    encrypt passwords = true
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    passdb backend = tdbsam
    dns proxy = no
    netbios name = Mainframe
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    default = media
    unix password sync = yes
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    os level = 20
    security = user
    lanman auth = yes
    syslog = 0
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    usershare allow guests = yes
    max log size = 1000
    pam password change = yes

 [media]
    browseable = yes
    writeable = yes
    path = /data/media
    write list = comma,separated,users
    valid users = comma,separated,users
    force create mode = 777
    force user = a-username
    user = comma,separated,users
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Solved" this by creating a smb user with the same user name I use in Windows 10.
And if I set the same password that I use in Windows, samba share does not asks for password. Otherwise, it will ask for password, but I use other user to login into it.
OR you can comment the line: **map to guest = bad user** and it will works fine.

Comment: Commenting out `map to guest = bad user` fixed it for me. Thanks!